# react navigation animated switch Page transition

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, variables, transition

I am developing a react native app When I am using

> react-navigation-animated-switch

for page transition effects. But want to know how to set up different transitions for each or selected pages.
 for example when I press the button A on page 1 it the effect should be slide-left and go to page B. When I press 'go back' button the effect should be slide-right and go back to page A. Below is the go back button code.

```
onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate(Paramnav)}
```

(NB:-'Paramnav' is a passed value from another page)

This is the page code for navigation page

```
import createAnimatedSwitchNavigator from 'react-navigation-animated-switch';
import {createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Transition } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import React from 'react';

import Login   from "./Page/A";
import SignUp  from './Page/B';

const Navigate1 = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
    A:         {screen:A},
    B:         {screen:B},
},
{
    transition: (
        <Transition.Together>
        <Transition.Out
            type="slide-left"
            durationMs={200}
            interpolation="easeIn" />
        <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={300} />
        </Transition.Together>
    ),
})

export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Navigate1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no known solution for specifying custom transitions for each screen in `createAnimatedSwitchNavigator`
The best thing to do would be to use `createStackNavigator`, which implements native transitions for both iOS and Android (new screens slide in from the right on iOS, fade in from the bottom on Android). Like requested, it runs the transitions backwards when you press back. Furthermore, you can also customize the transitions by passing `transitionConfig`.

You could do it like this:

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Transition } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import React from 'react';
import {
    Animated,
    Easing
} from 'react-native';

import Login   from "./Page/A";
import SignUp  from './Page/B';

//Slide from right animation
let SlideFromRight = (index, position, width) => {
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
  const translateX = position.interpolate({
    inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
    outputRange: [width, 0, 0]
  })
  const slideFromRight = { transform: [{ translateX }] }
  return slideFromRight
};

//Transition configurations for createStackNavigator
const TransitionConfiguration = () => {
  return {
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
      timing: Animated.timing,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    },
    screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
      const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
      const width = layout.initWidth;
      const { index } = scene
      return SlideFromRight(index, position, width);
    },
  }
}

const Navigate1 = createStackNavigator({
    A:         {screen:A},
    B:         {screen:B},
},
{
    headerMode: 'none', //No headers, like createAnimatedSwitchNavigator
    transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration //Configure transitions here
})

export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Navigate1);
```

This is a little complex, so I'm not going to dive into details, but you can read more about `createStackNavigator` [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) and about customizing `transitionConfig` [here](https://medium.com/@ksashrithbhat/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-screen-to-screen-c2d035aa3c63)